# How to create one dynamic array in Excel that is a concatenation of several dynamic arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have a function that returns a column. For a Minimal Working Example, please consider a name `randperm` as:

```
=LAMBDA(n,
    LET(ra, RANDARRAY(n),
        sorted_ra, SORT(ra), 
        XMATCH(ra, sorted_ra)
    )
)
```

Now what I'd like to get is (say) 5 *different* random permutations of (say) 4 numbers in a 4 x 5 array.

The most promising try has been:

`=IF(sequence(,5),randperm(4))`

which correctly produces a 4 x 5 array. But all the columns are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Horizontally Stack Random Columns

- Can't see anything beyond `REDUCE` combined with `HSTACK`:

```
=LET(n,4,cols,5,
REDUCE(RandPerm(n),SEQUENCE(cols-1),
    LAMBDA(rr,r,HSTACK(rr,RandPerm(n)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting... I never thought to use `REDUCE` to *increase* an array... If only we had the ability to add comments...

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make the custom `RANDPERM()` function recursive:

```
=LAMBDA(n,p,[initial_value],[start],
   LET(
   r, RANDARRAY(n),
   s, SORT(r),
   x, XMATCH(r, s),
   arr, IF(ISOMITTED(initial_value), x, HSTACK(initial_value, x)),
   c, IF(ISOMITTED(start), 1, start),
   IF(c<p, RANDPERM(n, p, arr, c+1), arr)))
```

**Results:**

[image: recursive_lambda.png]